# Are the list of questions that I am seeing curated based on my past activities?

Tags: support

I know that there are a few different options to sort questions based on popularity, views, tags etc etc. These options give the same list to anyone who uses them at that moment.

But is there any option which learns from my past activities (views, votes cast, votes received etc etc) to curate and sort a personalized list of questions? Is there a proposal to bring such a thing, not just for physics but other SE forums too?

Comment: There is such an algorithm on Stack Overflow, but not on other sites in the network. (Yet. Maybe someday in the future.)

Comment: Looks like there is some personalization for all SE sites, on the mobile app, but apparently it is not clear if and how it works: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231350/how-are-the-feeds-on-the-v1-0-ios-app-personalized

Answer (score 2):

The algorithm for the front-page display (https://physics.stackexchange.com/) uses your [favorite and ignored tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19173/what-do-favorite-tags-and-ignored-tags-do) to sort out new or recently active questions that might be interesting to you.

[If you do not set your favorite and ignored tags it will use your frequented tags instead.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/138187/2509)

Comment: Thanks. I am aware of using tags to explicitly curate my feed, but tag-alone option fails short most times. But is there a more intelligent algorithm that learns from my past? By the way, can you confirm if the automatic 'frequented tags' feature still works? Where can I find them for my profile?

Comment: The frequented tags feature only works if you have not configured any favorite or ignored tags, and it requires that you are pretty true to a small set of tags to do much.

Comment: I currently do not have any favorite/ignored tags set. Now, where can I find the auto-generated frequented tags? (There is one 'frequent' sort under Questions tab, but that is according to number of links)